# MySQL поиск в массиве в поле JSON

Tags: mysql, json, laravel

в столбце аттрибутов лежт такой json-чик

```
{
 "size":  [432, 433, 434], 
 "color": [17, 23, 56], 
 "brand": [36], 
 "type":  [12,13,14,15]
}
```

помогите составить запрос в laravel для поиска записей у которых имеется, ну например: color = 17

Спасибо

Comment: `->whereJsonContains('attribute->color', 17)`

Comment: спасибо! а если вместо 17 несколько значений color=[17,23]

Comment: `->whereJsonContains('attribute->color', [17, 23])` https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#json-where-clauses